# Whats closing this connection?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hey guys i need some help on my codes here i really dont know where is the part where it closes connection....what i want is to keep adding record until i clicked no from the msgbox

heres my code:

```
    Dim connstr As String = "server=localhost; uid= root; password=root; database=lmsdbase;"
Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter


    conn.ConnectionString = connstr



    Try
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        Else
            conn.Close()
            MsgBox("Database Connection Error")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Description)

        txtBookISBN.Focus()

    End Try



    Dim SqlStatement As String = "INSERT INTO tblIssue(ISBN, Title, BorrowerID, Name, Occupation, BorrowerType, School, DateIssued, DateToBeReturned) VALUES('" & txtBookISBN.Text & "','" & txtBTitle.Text & "','" & txtMemID.Text & "','" & txtMemName.Text & "','" & txtOccupation.Text & "','" & cboBtype.Text & "','" & txtSchool.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "','" & DateTimePicker2.Text & "')"
    Save(SqlStatement)

   Public Sub Save(ByRef SqlStatement As String)
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

    With cmd

        .CommandText = SqlStatement
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Connection = conn
        .ExecuteNonQuery()

    End With

    'conn.Close()
    MsgBox("Success!")


    If MsgBox("Do You Want to Add New Record?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then



        txtMemID.Text = ""
        txtMemName.Text = ""
        txtBookISBN.Text = ""
        txtBTitle.Text = ""
        txtOccupation.Text = ""
        cboBtype.Text = ""
        txtSchool.Text = ""

        txtMemID.Focus()

    Else


        Me.Close()


    End If

    conn.Dispose()

End Sub
```

Really appreciate your help

Comment: Have you got any error while executing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        Else
            conn.Close()
            MsgBox("Database Connection Error")
```

Doesn't this close all Open connections?

Comment: Why don't you debug & check?

Comment: already got it...it has some conflict with the other codes that i put in.

Comment: @BoyGeorge George: Good job :)